# Terraform: How to create block with dynamic and static content

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

For a resource, how can I create a block that has both dynamic and static content?  For the example below, all my azure key vaults will have a standard set of access policies, and a few have one or more additional policies. For this test key vault, I want to apply the dynamic block of access policies, as well as add a specific policy unique to this key vault only.

I've tried various ways to combine the two, but no luck.

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault" "key_vault-test" {
  name                   = "kv-test"
  location               = azurerm_resource_group.rg-webapps.location
  resource_group_name    = azurerm_resource_group.rg-webapps.name
  sku_name               = "standard"
  tenant_id              = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id

  dynamic "access_policy" {
    for_each = var.keyvault_accesspolicies
    content {
      tenant_id               = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
      object_id               = access_policy.value["object_id"]
      certificate_permissions = access_policy.value["certificate_permissions"]
      key_permissions         = access_policy.value["key_permissions"]
      secret_permissions      = access_policy.value["secret_permissions"]
    }
  }

  access_policy = [
    {
        tenant_id               = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
        object_id               = "<some guid>"
        application_id          = ""
        certificate_permissions = []
        key_permissions         = []
        secret_permissions      = [
          "Get"
        ]
        storage_permissions     = []
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are declaring ***static access policy*** in a wrong way . There shouldn't be an `"=["` after access policy .

**I tried with the below code and it successfully got added :**

```
provider "azurerm" {
    features {}
}

variable "keyvault_accesspolicies" {
    default = {
        one = {
            object_id="objectID1"
            certificate_permissions=["Get"]
            key_permissions=["Get"]
            secret_permissions=["Get"]     
        },
        second = {
            object_id="objectid2"
            certificate_permissions=["Get","List"]
            key_permissions=["Get","List"]
            secret_permissions=["Get","List"]  
        }
    }
}

data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "name" {
    name = "ansumantest"
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault" "key_vault-test" {
    name                   = "ansumankvtest12"
    location               = data.azurerm_resource_group.name.location
    resource_group_name    = data.azurerm_resource_group.name.name
    sku_name               = "standard"
    tenant_id              = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
    access_policy {
        tenant_id               = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
        object_id               = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id
        secret_permissions      = ["Get"]
    }
    dynamic "access_policy" {
        for_each = var.keyvault_accesspolicies
        content {
            tenant_id               = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
            object_id               = access_policy.value["object_id"]
            certificate_permissions = access_policy.value["certificate_permissions"]
            key_permissions         = access_policy.value["key_permissions"]
            secret_permissions      = access_policy.value["secret_permissions"]
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]